# After closing InAppBrowser, I am not able to move to next page

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I have been facing an issue with inappbrowser in ionic 3. In the below code in I am the case if payment is a success I want to move to Thankyoupage otherwise it has to stay on the same page. After payment success or failure, it is coming back to the same page, after closing inappbrowser. I am able to call this.navCtrl.push(ThankyouPage). I am seeing the undefined exception. Can anyone guide me to understand, where I made a mistake

```
      let option = 'location=no,hidden=yes';
  let url = "https://www.example.com/pay;
  const browser = this.inappBrowser.create(url,option);
  browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(function(event) {  
    if(event.url== "https://www.example.net/success.php"){          
      browser.close();
      //failuring here
      this.navCtrl.push(ThankyouPage);
    }
    if(event.url== "https://www.example.net/failure.php"){          
      browser.close();          
    }        
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let self=this;                            // add this line
    let option = 'location=no,hidden=yes';
  let url = "https://www.example.com/pay;
  const browser = this.inappBrowser.create(url,option);
  browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(function(event) {  
    if(event.url== "https://www.example.net/success.php"){          
      browser.close();
      //failuring here
      self.navCtrl.push(ThankyouPage);    // Update this statement 
   //self.navCtrl.push('ThankyouPage');    // Uncomment this if you use lazyloading
    }
    if(event.url== "https://www.example.net/failure.php"){          
      browser.close();          
    }        
  });
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, It is working thank you for ur help. I don't understand why this issue is coming. Is it an issue from ionic 3 or Is this it works this way only. I don't find any valid documentation about it. Can you please share more about it if possible?

Comment: It is works this way only.
Because if any function subscribe  ``(function(event) { ``` then this way it'll work.
or you can modify this function form ``(function(event) { ``  to  ``((event)=>{``